# Where does the term "dropship" come from?

Tags: terminology

I'm talking about those things:

[image]

They fly about in the sky, and when they land, enemy soldiers come out of them and try to kill you. Almost every video game has them, yet there is no such thing as a "dropship" in modern military. Where does the term come from?

Comment: It's used in science fiction in general, and is not exclusive to gaming. Nonetheless, since it has no real-life use, it might be of general interest to gamers.

Comment: I'm trying to find the first game to use it, which would be a first step. There is Starcraft in 98 (Terran Dropship) but there's also Dune 2 in 92 (Harkonnen Drop-ship) although, it was taken from a concept art for the 84 movie.

Comment: There are plenty of such things in the military, they just don't have rocket engines and descend from space.

Comment: It was also used in Battletech manuals and in Sci-Fi magazine/journals as the term for this type of craft ~1986/1987. [Interesting ngram search?](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dropship%2Cdrop-ship&year_start=1800&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdropship%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrop%20-%20ship%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdropship%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrop%20-%20ship%3B%2Cc0). Anything before 1985 seems to describe a method of shipping products from catalogues straight from manufacturer, rather than stock

Comment: C-130 Hercules, V-22 Osprey, C-17 Globemaster, H47 Chinook, etc. are all famous  (U.S.) military "dropships" in real life. The concept of airborne troop transport is as old military use of aircraft -- it predates even WWII.

Comment: @Fana The game Cosmic Ark (1982) has a small ship that drops from the mothership and returns to it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't think it belongs on this site; an expert gamer is not more likely to be able to answer this question than a complete non-gamer.

Comment: May be on topic at [scifi.se]

Comment: I thought it came from Starship Troopers, though I may be misremembering.

Comment: @DJClayworth this seems to be the full text of Starship Troopers https://archive.org/stream/StarshipTroopersRobertHeinlein/Starship_Troopers_-_Robert_Heinlein_djvu.txt  but I don't see the term.  And the serialized version (Starship Soldier) part 1: https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v017n04_1959-10_PDF/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v017n04_1959-10_PDF_djvu.txt and part 2: https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v017n05_1959-11_PDF/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v017n05_1959-11_PDF_djvu.txt

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a better fit for Scifi.stackexchange (where this term originates from far longer than the scope of video games), or even english.stackexchange, for etymology purposes.

Comment: @DJClayworth I see where it says "The other half are the spaceships that drop us and the capsules we drop in" though.

Comment: @senpai the word dropship is not in the english dictionary. Dropship became popular with games, not science-fiction comic books.

Comment: Question is not off-topic: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

3rd point: Game mechanics and terminology

Dropship is a game term. Read rules before aimlessly clicking on buttons

Comment: @AzulShiva That's debatable, but not a game term exclusively in any case. I also doubt that a long-standing member of this community is aimlessly clicking on buttons. I didn't close it at first, like I mentioned, but I don't see any proper ground to reopen it.

Comment: @Joachim It doesn't matter wether it's a game term exclusively or not. It is a game term. And it's not an official word.

Comment: Everything points to the word being a word used in (science) fiction. And your second point depends on how one interprets 'official' in this context. If the meaning is obvious but the use is irregular and niche, it can still be a perfectly fine word absent from dictionaries.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The term "dropship" was used in the December 1983 issue of *Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine* in the story "Remembering Siri" by Dan Simmons.

[Page 36](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v07n12_1983-12/page/n35):

> There were only five of us in the **dropship**. It was always a thrill to me to fall out of high orbit into the atmosphere of a real world.

Used also on pages 38 and 62.

Much earlier, in the July 1960 *Amazing Science Fiction Stories* in "All the Stars a Stage" by James Blish:

[page 84](https://archive.org/details/Amazing_Stories_v34n07_1960-07_cape1736/page/n83)

> There was the beginning of a
> muted stir throughout the Javelin, as battle gear and **drop
> ships** began to be readied.

There is a very detailed 1978 description in [Analog Science Fiction/science Fact](https://books.google.com/books?id=La46AQAAIAAJ&q=%22drop-ships%20being%20scrapped%20in%20a%20%22&dq=%22drop-ships%20being%20scrapped%20in%20a%20%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizp6jrmtblAhUix1kKHTbLCpEQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg) (also in [Best Science Fiction of the Year, Volume 7](https://books.google.com/books?id=_RU435nsXwgC&q=%22drop-ships%20being%20scrapped%20in%20a%20%22&dq=%22drop-ships%20being%20scrapped%20in%20a%20%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizp6jrmtblAhUix1kKHTbLCpEQ6AEwAXoECAAQAg)):

> Because Celia's father was in the mining business, Lisa Maria batted her eyes at a handsome **drop-ship** jockey and he took them out to see one of the **drop-ships** being scrapped in a flickering of cutting torches. These were perhaps the heaviest spaceships ever built by man, rivaling in weight battleships of the Yamato class, but had only one flight in them, down. The jockeys who rode them to Earth called them rafts. They were assembled crudely of massive metal in a low orbit and needed to be able to perform only two functions: to hold together while they burned off their heat shield in the atmosphere and to float when they hit the water. Sometimes they were scrapped at Tongaro and sometimes towed all the way to San Francisco or San Diego or Yokahama.

But the oldest example is not from science fiction.  Instead it is an actual military drop ship.

Richard C. Hottelet was a reporter who flew along with the 24 March 1945 Operation Varsity and wrote in a 5 May 1945 [article](https://books.google.com/books?id=LaBCAQAAIAAJ&q=%22drop%20ships%22&dq=%22drop%20ships%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwig3Y2AgNflAhWFneAKHX8fAAM4ChDoATAEegQIAhAC) in Collier's Magazine:

> hundreds of C-47s flying along in tight formation ...
>
> The three photographers, their cameras clicking away, jostled one another at the waist windows as we swooped around the **drop ships**.
>
> P-Hour, the drop hour for the paratroops, was 10 a.m.

So the original "drop ships" were [C-47s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_C-47_Skytrain).

Comment: "**fall** out of high orbit".  **This** is what a dropship is.  **Shuttles fly** out of the mothership, but dropships are... **dropped**.  That's why they're called **drop**ships, not shuttles.

Comment: Hey, DavePhD, funny seeing you with a "New contributor" tag.

Comment: @RonJohn On the contrary, in the earliest sense it was the *cargo* that dropped, not the ship. (At least if all went well.)

Answer (score 21):

The term was popularized in *Aliens(1986)*, where the military shuttle is referred to Cheyenne **Dropship**. Concept of dropship is very similar to space shuttle, a small craft meant to ferry passengers or cargo around.

What Aliens did, essentially, was to popularize term *dropship* to specifically refer to military shuttles. Shuttlecraft (another term not from real world, but borrowing term *shuttle* from the real world) had already been codified by *Star Trek* to specifically mean small craft meant to travel between mothership and planetary bodies for short distances, as opposed to longer distance made by starships.

Dropships do not exist in real world because the term was specifically coined for scifi. However, there have been concepts of a dropship for Mars travel, where a mothership "drops" shuttles into Martian athmosphere and they travel the rest of the way on their own power. In essence, being dropships, or dropshuttles.

**TL;DR**

*Aliens* called military shuttles dropships first (as far as I have been able to find) and everyone else followed the lead. Possible term variants might have existed before, but *Aliens* is the trope codifier.

Comment: This does not answer the question, though.

Comment: First know usage of term "dropship" comes from Aliens. There is no real story beyond that. Aliens creators used the term dropship and everyone followed the example of "military shuttles are known as dropships". There is no records of where the Aliens writers got the name. Most likely they just made it up on the spot.

Comment: The only thing that *could possibly* be added (that is, I've not been able to verify it as I don't have a copy of the Starship Troopers novel to hand) - is that the use in Alien *might* come from Starship Toopers. https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/UD-4L_Cheyenne_Dropship (see "Behind The Scenes" -> "Design"). Definitely it seems in the book, the act of landing on a planet from the ship is known as a "drop". Really hard to verify though, as all sources discussing it use the term "dropship" freely as it's become part of standard sci-fi vocabulary.

Comment: Actually just on the above, ngram seems to suggest there might have been a use of the word dropship in the 1940s, and then a significant surge in use from the early 60s. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dropship&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdropship%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdropship%3B%2Cc00 That said, the leap of use after 1986 when Aliens releases - is massive - and definitely marks a solid point where it became suddenly more popular.

Comment: Yeah, which is why I decided to cite Aliens as the source. IIRC the "drop ships" (two words instead of one) of Starship Troopers serve as different role from the "dropship"(single word). That is to say, their job to fly to combat zone and literally DROP the MI and maybe later come pick them up as slower pace. Where as the dropship, as popularized by Aliens, has dropships land, deploy troops and then take off. Effectively, they are military tactical air/space transports (Something like Osprey, Blackhawk or Chinook).

Comment: Added extra mention that Aliens might not be original source of the term, but it is the one that codified the term.

Comment: As per the design section: "The name itself is likely taken from Robert A. Heinlien's [sic] 1959 novel *Starship Troopers*, in which similar craft are used to deploy ground forces on other planets". Google Ngram shows the first occurence of the word around 1943 (wanted to post that as answer based on another answer that has been deleted, but figured it might be considered an attack on this answer :).

Comment: As noted, "likely taken", not "taken". We are not sure. Also, term might have been used before *but* it didn't achieve its meaning until Aliens, when it was commonly accepted to mean "military transport shuttle". If you look at pre-Alien and post-Alien uses of "dropship", post-Alien dropship strongly resemble use and design (in rough terms) to that of Aliens dropship. That is to say, a military transport craft.

Also, I don't take someone posting alternative answer as an attack. This is supposed to be "questions and answers", not just an answer.

Comment: Good point. But didn't achieve what?

Comment: Just finished editing my post.

Comment: If you consider the Mars dropships (i.e. shuttle to atmo) as fitting the "dropship" designation (i.e. troops to ground), then I'm going argue in favor of the [Curiosity Sky Crane](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1WX0CATyn8) already being an existing example of such a Martian dropship. It fits the designation even better because it actually drops its payload on the surface instead of somewhere in atmo.

Comment: Well, main difference (as far as I have read) is that the hypothetical Mars dropship (which is purely a concept at this point, not an actual thing) would actually be able to leave. The Curiosity Sky Crane is closer to what is commonly known as a drop pod. A pod that contains stuff and gets dropped at the target to deliver the payload. Of course, difference between drop pod and bomb is that drop pod doesn't explode (by design, at least)

In contrast, Sky Crane delivers the cargo and then goes off to crash, clearing the delivery zone. It's a single-use thing.

Comment: In the context of videogames especially, many other common tropes originated in Aliens.